# How to play audio from an array in JavaScript, like it's done with sounddevice in python

Tags: javascript, python, audio

In python I can use modules like `pyaudio` to play from an array of amplitudes, using a code like this:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

waveform = np.random.uniform(-1,1,348207) #generating a random array of sound amplitudes
sd.play(waveform, samplerate = 44100) #playing the generated audio
sd.wait()
```

But I need do make something like this happen in a browser i.e. play the audio from an array of amplitudes using **JavaScript** in the client side of an web application. I looked around for ways to do this, but couldn't find any information.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to do what another stackoverflow post used in order to play audio from a byte array in JavaScript, but turns out a byte array is totally different thing from an amplitude array. Then, I looked around in other places and found no any information regarding how to even start this.

Comment: update your question and post your html and javascript